# Google Chrome is redirecting before visiting a shopping website

Tags: malware, chrome, url-redirection

I notice every few days (~5 days) that when I try to open an Amazon.in URL, before opening that URL, Chrome opens a different link which looks like an affiliate link. This link redirects to the actual URL. The link is given below. After it does so, it will stop behaving like this for next few days.

Is my computer infected?

Here is what Chrome opens before redirecting to Amazon: `http://redirect.afflepay.com/aff_c?offer_id=1021&aff_id=1250&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.in%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2F1841591572%2Fref%3Ds9_qpp_gw_d99_g14_i7_r`

Comment: Have you scanned for a virus and/or other malware?

Comment: Nope. I thought OS X doesn't need those.

Answer (score 1):

**Most probably it's a malicious extension**
Sometimes when you install software, the installer installs extensions to your browsers along with it. If you have recently installed a software from an untrusted site, it could have installed this extension on your browser.

You can try the following things:

- Visit Amazon from some other browser to see if it's only a chrome problem
- Check the extensions on all the affected browsers to see if there is any extension that you don't remember adding
- If that doesn't solve your problem then go the advanced browser settings and check for any funny business

Answer (score 0):

Block these two websites:

`1. decademcical.com
 2. mutualvehemence.com`

ISP Problem. Check [Same Problem Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/191260/clicking-web-page-taking-me-to-adware-malware)